# Within the filter, how can I combine multiple medium types?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

When filtering for medium or source, Google Analytic's filter doesn't allow me to filter by two different mediums.

[image: example photo]

For example, in the attached photo, I would like the final filtered result to include all mediums of "cpc" and also any medium containing the keyword "paid".

Using the "Advanced Filter" does not work because it operates in such a way that the searched medium must satisfy each dimension -- meaning, the single medium must contain the strings "paid" and "cpc".

Is there a way to narrow down the results by inclusion of parameters instead of by excluding the non-desired parameters (I can make this work by excluding one by one, but this won't be practical with a long list of mediums)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the filter, rather than using the match type "Containing", use match type "Matching RegExp" and enter cpc|paid.

A | (pipe character) means "or" and the regular expression should capture all mediums that contain cpc or paid.

[image]